# How to connect to OSM api using osmar package of R language?

Tags: r, openstreetmap

I am trying to connect to OSM api using [osmar](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/osmar/index.html) package of R language. But I am getting this error all the time:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Could not resolve host: api.openstreetmap.org
```

My code is as following:

```
library(raster)
library(osmar) 

osm.extend <- corner_bbox(11.35149, 47.10107, 11.39610, 47.13505)

osm <- get_osm(osm.extend, source = osmsource_api())
```

[Here at get_osm() I am getting the eror!]

P.S: I am actually following [this](http://giswerk.org/doku.php?id=r:r-tutorials:packages:osmar) article to understand how to extract tagged data from open street map using R.

I would be really thankful for helping in this issue. Thanks for the time!

Comment: This works for me. Perhaps `update.packages()` ?

Comment: Are you behind a HTTP proxy?

Comment: RoertH, yes I updated the packages and still I get the same error!

Comment: @scai, thanks for the hint. YES I was being blocked by the network in which I was logged in. It is working fine now! :)